# Selecting a charge time for a NiMH charger at 1C

Tags: battery-charging, solar-energy, nimh

I'm building a solar charger for an Energizer 8.4 V, 175 mAh NiMH battery with a [MAX713](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX712-MAX713.pdf). The solar panel is 15.4 V, 200 mA. If I charge them at 1C (175 mA), would it be better to set the charge time to 66 or 90 minutes?

I also have some EBL batteries of the same format, but I'm not too worried about overcharging them, since I'll just buy more Energizer's since they're rated higher (I discharged the EBL's at 35 mA, like in the Energizer datasheet, and only got 150 mAh despite the 280 mAh printed on the label).

Answer (score 0):

In most configurations, the charge timer in the MAX713 is there to stop charging when the \$-\frac{dV}{dt}\$ (and/or \$\frac{dT}{dt}\$) algorithms fail; it then does not "set the charging time", but acts as a fail-safe. End-of-charge is normally determined by an algorithm the MAX713 implements, not by the time you set.

The \$-\frac{dV}{dt}\$ algorithm can be disabled when setting the maximum charging time, but then the MAX713 becomes just a current source with a timer, which defeats most of its purpose.

If you use it like that, I would set the timer to 66 minutes at 1C to make sure there is no overcharging; NiMH cells don't like that. You won't get full capacity, though: charging efficiency is good for NiMH up to about 90% SoC, but empty batteries may not be fully charged after 66 minutes when charging at 1C.

Also note that using a solar panel as a power supply for the MAX713 may not deliver a constant input current at all times, which *will* play havoc with the charging algorithm used by the MAX713.

Also, the solar panel won't be used at its MPP when used like this and deliver less than its potential maximum power, but that is another matter.

Comment: can you suggest a link to a mppt circuit I can use with this panel?

Comment: Any standard MPPT charger will deliver a varying current, depending on changing light conditions, and the \$-\frac{dV}{dt}\$ detection for NiMH doesn't play nice with a varying charging current, so no, not off the top of my head.